# Using a KS0108 type screen for a portable terminal

Tags: screen, driver

I would like to use a KS0108 type for a terminal (it is desirable for its low power use, around 5-7 amps), I cannot seem to find drivers and would like to know where to start on writing my own drivers or hacking together something that gets around it.

If possible can I make a virtual HDMI port or Character LCD that I can use to control the screen over GPIO? If not, what would be the best place to start to learn how to write drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used that kind of screen, but [this](https://github.com/Mezgrman/pyLCD) is supposed to drive it.

EDIT: how to read and write data from and to terminal in python.
You'll need to import os:

`import os`

Then, to write a command to the terminal use, ie:

`os.system('ls')`

and to read from it:

`print run_command('your_command_here')`

EDIT2: I don't know if this will work, but seems to me like the better aproach if possible:

Create a software serial port under GPIO and wire the hardware serial port to the serial software port, then, create a python script that starts @reboot and reads the terminal TX and print it on the screen.

EDIT3: I've found [this](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/raspberry-pi-2nd-uart-a-k-a-bit-banging-a-k-a-software-serial). Seems to explain how to create more uart ports.

Comment: I saw that but it seems its not actually drivers, it just allows you to control the display with python.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it's possible to create a sketch that reads and write to the terminal, but not sure if that would be completely possible.

Comment: that would work but I'm not familiar with console interactions in python and I dont know how to deal with programs that take inputs (ex the python console) and what to do about curses(ex nano).

Comment: I've edited the answer to add info about the terminal, but I don't know if this will fit you, because it will only get the output form the command that you send, not the whole terminal.